# To make the following query run in one sec in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have the following query to retrieve the top 10 orders that were not shipped before a certain date:

```
select top 10 *
from
(
        select 
                o_orderkey,
                o_shippriority,
                o_orderdate,
                sum(l_extendedprice * (1-l_discount)) over (partition by l.l_orderkey,l.l_partkey,l.l_suppkey ) as potential_revenue
                from
                lineitem l
                inner join
                neworders o
                on l.l_orderkey=o.o_orderkey
                where
                l.l_shipdate > '2014-08-05' 
                and o_orderstatus ='O'

) A
order by potential_revenue desc;
```

Lineitem has 60M records and orders has 15M records.

The `l_shipdate` and `l_orderkey` is a clustered index that is partitioned on `date` and `o_orderkey` is the clustered index for the `orders table`. I also created a non-clustered index on the `o-orderstatus` column. The query is taking 11 seconds to run and I am wondering what else can be done to improve the performance of the query?

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan - that should give you a better idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try these indexes.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Ix_neworders ON neworders (o_orderstatus) INCLUDE (o_orderdate,  o_shippriority);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Ix_lineitem ON lineitem (l_extendedprice) 
INCLUDE (l_discount,  l_partkey,l_suppkey );
```

Anyway TOP is expensive operation.
When you look to explain plan take a look to key lookups. 
If you have them, then try to create proper index + pay attention to index scan. 
Try to make them index seeks with indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try them. Another question I had is on the index scan. Even though I created Partitioned index on the l_shipdate, it is still doing a clustered index scan , probably because of the condition l.l_shipdate > '2014-08-05' (it is scanning all the partitions). Is there a way to avoid that.

Comment: Most probably you forgot to add some columns or put them to include instead of index. Can you give real table DDLs?